# Limit query to ignore elements descendants

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to query the following XML to build some objects which copy the folder hierarchy outlined in the XML.

```
<ShareList>
    <Title>Documantis</Title>
    <Url>/sites/dev/Documantis/Forms/AllItems.aspx</Url>
    <Guid>fed8f456-efa9-4fe5-8b97-46734a3040b6</Guid>
    <HasUniqueScopes>False</HasUniqueScopes>
    <RootFolder>/sites/dev</RootFolder>
    <Children>
        <ShareListItem>
            <Title>First</Title>
            <Url>Documantis/First</Url>
            <HasUniqueRole>False</HasUniqueRole>
            <IsSubFolder>False</IsSubFolder>
            <PermissionMask>FullMask</PermissionMask>
            <Children>
                <ShareListItem>
                    <Title>Second</Title>
                    <Url>Documantis/First/Second</Url>
                    <HasUniqueRole>False</HasUniqueRole>
                    <IsSubFolder>False</IsSubFolder>
                    <ParentGuid>22b2a7e9-a42e-497f-aad3-8caa85f6ac6d</ParentGuid>
                </ShareListItem>
            </Children>
        </ShareListItem>
        <ShareListItem>
            <Title>Folda</Title>
            <Url>Documantis/Folda</Url>
            <HasUniqueRole>False</HasUniqueRole>
            <IsSubFolder>False</IsSubFolder>
            <PermissionMask>FullMask</PermissionMask>
        </ShareListItem>
    </Children>
</ShareList>
```

I'm having trouble finding a way to return one level of the `<ShareListItem>` elements at a time, with my current code it returns all the ShareListItems in one List which doesn't represent the hierarchy accurately.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(sharepointXml);

XElement root;
using (XmlReader xr = new XmlNodeReader(doc)) { root = XElement.Load(xr); }

var result = from child in root.DescendantsAndSelf("ShareList") //.Elements("ShareList") // Descendants("ShareList")
             select child;

foreach (XElement xml in result)
{
    // Build ListItem from results
    ShareList list = new ShareList()
    {
        Title = xml.Element("Title").Value,
        Url = xml.Element("Url").Value,
        Guid = xml.Element("Guid").Value,
        HasUniqueScopes = Convert.ToBoolean(xml.Element("HasUniqueScopes").Value),
        RootFolder = xml.Element("RootFolder").Value,
    };

    if (xml.Element("Children") != null)
    {
        var subResult = from child in xml.Element("Children").Descendants("ShareListItem")
                        select child;

        foreach (XElement subXml in subResult)
        {
            // results here are flat and don't show depth of nodes
        }
        //list.Children =
    }
```

I could recursively infer the hierarchy's structure from the URL Element, however I already have it represented in XML so I would rather learn how to return this through a query.

**Edit:**

Here's what I ended up using

```
public List<ShareList> HandleLists(XElement levelRoot)
{
    List<ShareList> lists = new List<ShareList>();

    var results = from list in levelRoot.DescendantsAndSelf("ShareList")
                 select list;

    foreach (var list in results)
    {
        var children = list.Element("Children");
        if (children == null)
            return null;

        ShareList shareList = new ShareList()
        {
            Title = list.Element("Title").Value,
            Url = list.Element("Url").Value,
            Guid = list.Element("Guid").Value,
            HasUniqueScopes = Convert.ToBoolean(list.Element("HasUniqueScopes").Value),
            RootFolder = list.Element("RootFolder").Value,
            // Recursively find ListItem folders
            Children = HandleSubfolders(list)
        };
        lists.Add(shareList);
    }
    return lists;
}

public List<ShareListItem> HandleSubfolders(XElement levelRoot)
{
    List<ShareListItem> subfolders = new List<ShareListItem>();

    // All nodes deeper than current
    var children = levelRoot.Element("Children");
    if (children == null)
        return null;

    // Subfolders
    var items = children.Elements("ShareListItem");
    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        ShareListItem listItem = new ShareListItem()
        {
            Title = item.Element("Title").Value,
            Url = item.Element("Url").Value,
            HasUniqueRole = Convert.ToBoolean(item.Element("HasUniqueRole").Value),
            IsSubfolder = Convert.ToBoolean(item.Element("IsSubFolder").Value),
            PermissionMask = item.Element("PermissionMask").Value,
            PermissionMaskName = item.Element("PermissionMaskName").Value,
            // Recursively find ListItem subfolders
            Children = HandleSubfolders(item)
        };
        // Add subfolder to Children collection
        subfolders.Add(listItem);
    }
    return subfolders;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to use recursion here.

Create a method that handles one level of the hierarchy and calls itself with the next level.

```
public void HandleLevel(XElement levelRoot)
{
    PerformAction(levelRoot);

    var children = levelRoot.Element("Children");
    if(children == null)
        return;
    var items = children.Elements("ShareListItem");
    foreach(var item in item)
    {
        // Handle child's children:
        HandleLevel(item);
    }
}
```

`PerformAction` is the code that actually does, whatever you want to do for each document.
The way the code is currently structured, this action is also executed for the root document `/sites/dev/Documantis/Forms/AllItems.aspx`.
If you don't want this simply move `PerformAction` into the `foreach` loop and pass `item` instead of `levelRoot`.

BTW: Your initialization of the root element is *very* strange.
You can simply use this:

```
var root = XDocument.Parse(sharepointXml).Root;
```

The initial call to `HandleLevel` would simply look like this:

```
HandleLevel(root);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I like how this example is split into small methods I think that makes code easier to maintain.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is by creating Classes to represent the hierarchy like so:

```
public class ShareList {
    ...
    public List<ShareList> Children { get; set; }
}
```

In your code, refactor the traversing part into a method that accepts a Sharelist node and traverse it, calling itself for each Children node:

```
private Sharelist RecurseHierarchy(XElement sharelistNode, ShareList parent)
{
    // your traversing code goes here
    // get your data and create a new Sharelist object
    // if it has a children node, traverse it and call this same method on the child
    // Sharelist nodes
    parent.Title = sharelistNode.Element("Title").Value;        


    var children = sharelistNode.Element("Children");

    if (children != null)
    {
        var items = children.Elements("ShareListItem");
        foreach(var listItem in items)
        {
            ShareList childShareList = new ShareList();
            parent.Children.Add(childShareList);

            RecurseHierarchy(listItem, childShareList);
        }
    }

    // Just in case we want to chain some method
    return parent;
}
```

To call it initially, you will have to pass in the root node and a new ShareList object.

Comment: That's exactly how my ShareList class works already :)
Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

A good way of producing the results your after is by using XPath ([here](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp)'s a good primer if you need it).

Once you've got your XML into an XmlDocument you can return different bits of it by using an XPathNavigator, like this:

```
var xmlNavigator = xmlDocument.CreateNavigator();

var outerQuery = xmlNavigator.Select("ShareList/Children/ShareListItem");

while (outerQuery.MoveNext()) {
    Console.WriteLine(outerQuery.Current.SelectSingleNode("Title").Value);
    var innerQuery = outerQuery.Current.Select("Children/ShareListItem");
    while (innerQuery.MoveNext()) {
        Console.WriteLine(" - " + innerQuery.Current.SelectSingleNode("Title").Value);
    }
}
```

In the code above, we query the XML for all ShareListItem nodes within Children nodes of the root ShareList node, and store the resultant XPathNodeIterator in the variable outerQuery.  We then iterate over all the nodes found, and run an operation as well as another XPath query on each to retrieve child nodes to process.  The code above produces the following output:

> First
>    - Second
>   Folda

Which I think it what you're after.  Obviously, you can use recursion if necessary if your XML can be nested more deeply than this.